# Excel VBA to copy column to existing workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have Workbook, **source.xlsm**, Worksheet **"test1" Column A6:A20** that I need to copy to another WorkBook located on my C:... named **dest.xlsx**, **Worksheet "Assets"**, **Column "I"**. I need to be able to copy  the data and be able to add to the column without overwriting the previous data copied. Any help would be a life saver.

```
Sub Align()
    Dim TargetSh As String

    TargetSh = "Assets"

    For Each WSheet In Application.Worksheets

        If WSheet.Name <> TargetSh Then
            WSheet.Select
            Range("A6:A20").Select
            Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets(TargetSh).Select
            lastRow = Range("I65532").End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next WSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: `Any help would be a life saver` Definitely :) Could you show us what have you tried?

Comment: How would I format the code to not be bunched up?

Comment: you can use the ` and ` to surround the codes. If they are still not in the correct format then one of us will edit it for you:)

Comment: paste this code in your question above and then delete the above comment

Comment: I know this is to copy sheet to sheet within the same Workbook, but I need to have it copy to another workbook as noted above
Sub Align() Dim TargetSh as String TargetSh = "Assets" For Each WSheet In Application.Worksheets If WSheet.Name <> TargetSh Then WSheet.Select Range("A6:A20").Select Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select Selection.Copy Sheets(TargetSh).Select LastRow = Range("I65532").End(xlUp).Row Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Select ActiveSheet.Paste End If Next WSheet End Sub

Comment: Seems like you misunderstood me, I have pasted your code in the above question :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying? I have **not tested** it but I think it should work. Let me know if you get any errors.

```
Sub Sample_Copy()
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("test1")

    '~~> Change path as applicable
    Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open("C:\dest.xlsx")
    Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets("Assets")

    lastRow = wsTemp.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ws.Range("A6:A20").Copy wsTemp.Range("I" & lastRow)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    '~~> Cleanup
    wbTemp.Close savechanges:=True
    Set wb = Nothing: Set wbTemp = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing: Set wsTemp = Nothing
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: Absolutely masterful. Its amazing how obvious it is when you see it written out so well.

Comment: tsk tsk ... you flatterer! LOL. Jokes apart. Glad to be of help :)